# Update ChartJS line chart from DynamoDB query

Tags: javascript, amazon-dynamodb, chart.js

I am trying to display a live line chart of DynamoDB data as it is collected.
The chart has 3 ranges of data that it will show (last 30 days, last 7 days, last 24 hrs). When a range is selected DynamoDB will be queried and a ChartJS line chart is created. After the initial chart is drawn, Dynamo will be queried again every 5 seconds, and the chart will be updated with the results of the new query.

For some reason, the .update() call is adding duplicate data to the chart. I am sure that this is because the query will pull some of the same data as the original query, but I was under the impression that an update call will rerender the chart's data, so I don't understand why there would be duplicate data.

Here is relevant code:

```
var getDateTimeStr = function(hours){
  //create a string of the date and time 30 days ago
  var ts = new Date().getTime();
  var tsYest = (ts - (hours /*hrs in 30 days*/ * 3600) * 1000);
  var d = new Date(tsYest);
  var yestDateStr = d.getFullYear() + '/'
  + ('0' + (d.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + '/'
  + ('0' + d.getDate()).slice(-2) + ' '
  + ('0' + (d.getHours()+1)).slice(-2) + ':'
  + ('0' + (d.getMinutes()+1)).slice(-2) + ':'
  + ('0' + (d.getSeconds()+1)).slice(-2);
  console.log(yestDateStr);
  return yestDateStr;
}

//PARAMETERS FOR 3 RANGES
var params1 = {
  TableName: "O2Sensor_data",
  ConsistenRead: false,
  ScanindexForward: true,
  KeyConditionExpression: "sensor_id = :sensor AND #dtdt >= :start_date",
  ExpressionAttributeNames: {
  "#dtdt": "DateTime"
},
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ":sensor": "sensor1",
    ":start_date": getDateTimeStr(720)
  }
}

var params2 = {
  TableName: "O2Sensor_data",
  ConsistenRead: false,
  ScanindexForward: true,
  KeyConditionExpression: "sensor_id = :sensor AND #dtdt >= :start_date",
  ExpressionAttributeNames: {
    "#dtdt": "DateTime"
  },
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ":sensor": "sensor1",
    ":start_date": getDateTimeStr(168)
  }
}

var params3 = {
  TableName: "O2Sensor_data",
  ConsistenRead: false,
  ScanindexForward: true,
  KeyConditionExpression: "sensor_id = :sensor AND #dtdt >= :start_date",
  ExpressionAttributeNames: {
    "#dtdt": "DateTime"
  },
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ":sensor": "sensor1",
    ":start_date": getDateTimeStr(24)
  }
}

//DYNAMODB QUERY FUNCTION
function chartCreate(params, color){
    console.log("Querying DynamoDB");
    docClient.query(params, function(err, data){
      if(err) console.log(err, err.stack);
      else{
        DateTimeArr = [];
        o2readingArr = [];
        data.Items.forEach(function(item){
          DateTimeArr.push(item.DateTime.toString());
          o2readingArr.push(item.o2percent.toString());
  });

      var dataMap = {
        type: 'line',
        data: {//displays readings form sensor based on the range selected
          labels: DateTimeArr,
          datasets: [{
            label: '% O2 In Air',
            data: o2readingArr,
            backgroundColor: color
          },
          {//creates a line at 19.5% to see if data readings are below safe         value
            label: "19.5%",
            data: Array.apply(null, new  Array(o2readingArr.length)).map(Number.prototype.valueOf, 19.5),
            fill: false,
            radius: 0,
            borderColor: "rgba(0,0,0,.5)"
          }]//end of datasets
        },
        options: {
          animation: false,
          responsive: true,
          scaleOverride: true
        }
      };//end of dataMap var declaration

      //CREATE CHART
      var ctx = document.getElementById("lineChart").getContext("2d");
        ctx.canvas.width = 600;
        ctx.canvas.height = 256;
      window.datChart = new Chart(ctx, dataMap);
    }//end of else statement
  });//end of query function
}

function chartUpdate(params){
  console.log("Querying DynamoDB");
  docClient.query(params, function(err, data){
    if(err) console.log(err, err.stack);
    else{
      data.Items.forEach(function(item){
        DateTimeArr.push(item.DateTime.toString());
        o2readingArr.push(item.o2percent.toString());
       });
    }
  });
}

function chooseChart(){
  if(window.datChart){window.datChart.destroy();}
  if(document.getElementById("sel1").value == "last30"){
    currParams = params1;
    currColor = "rgba(0,0,255,.8)";
    chartCreate(params1, "rgba(0,0,255,.8)");
  }//blue
  else if(document.getElementById("sel1").value == "last7"){
    currParams = params2;
    currColor = "rgba(0,255,0,.8)";
    chartCreate(params2, "rgba(0,255,0,.8)");
  }//green
  else if(document.getElementById("sel1").value == "last24"){
    currParams = params3;
    currColor = "rgba(255,0,0,.8)";
    chartCreate(params3, "rgba(255,0,0,.8)");
  }//red
  else{console.log("something went wrong in chooseChart function");}
}

chooseChart();

setInterval(function(){
  window.datChart.destroy();
  chartUpdate(currParams);
  window.datChart.update();
}, 5000);
```

I have tried other ways such as completely redrawing the chart each time, but this causes blinking on the web page which is rather annoying. I'm not sure how I can get this to work so that the chart updates with only new data.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can't find the issue without looking at what values params1, params2 and params3 variables has. Also, when you push the data into DateTimeArr, please check whether the array already has the data and push it only if it is not available.

Comment: edited to include params values

Comment: @notionquest i wrote a function to check whether the array already contains the data as you suggested and it works

Comment: Glad it worked!

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a function to check for dates that are already stored in the array and it appears to be working well now.

Here is the function:

```
var isinArr = function(str){
  for(i=0; i<DateTimeArr.length; i++){
    if(str === DateTimeArr[i]){
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

And here is the updated chartUpdate() function:

```
function chartUpdate(params){
  console.log("Querying DynamoDB");
  docClient.query(params, function(err, data){
    if(err) console.log(err, err.stack);
    else{
      data.Items.forEach(function(item){
        if(!isinArr(item.DateTime.toString())){
          DateTimeArr.push(item.DateTime.toString());
          o2readingArr.push(item.o2percent.toString());
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```